# Using SignalR in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm starting work with `Kotlin` as my new language for android application development And I need to work with `SignalR` library for sending and receiving messages from the server. I found this [link](https://github.com/Gurgen/SignalR-.net-core-android-client) for working with `java` language but nothing for `Kotlin`.

Comment: you can still use stuff made in java in kotlin

Comment: I know and You are right @tyczj but working with `Kotlin` style is very exciting for me. And I wanna write this project entirely with `Kotlin`

Comment: You can though...you can use classes made in java in kotlin classes so you are writing it all in kotlin. how do you think you are able to use the android SDK thats in java?